# Pointer continues moving after stopping finger

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, mouse-pointer

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon (5th Gen.). There seems to be some sort of mouse deceleration, i.e. when I stop moving my finger, the pointer continues in the same direction for a couple millimeters. If I immediately remove my finger, the pointer stops. How do I fix this? I have a similar problem with Fedora 25.